Open telemtery - pushing application logs to OTEL collector using OpenTelemetrySdk
I am trying to push the data to OTEL collector in the following way .
@Configuration
public class OpenTelemetryLogConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public OpenTelemetrySdk initializeOpenTelemetryConfig() {

        BatchLogRecordProcessor processor = BatchLogRecordProcessor.builder(
                OtlpHttpLogRecordExporter.builder()
                    .setEndpoint(String.valueOf(URI.create("http://10.20.36.68:4317/v1/logs"))) 
                    .build())
            .build();

        OpenTelemetrySdk sdk = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
            .setLoggerProvider(
                SdkLoggerProvider.builder()
                    .addLogRecordProcessor(processor)
                    .build())
            .build();

        // Add hook to close SDK, which flushes logs
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(sdk::close));
        io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.appender.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender.install(
            sdk);
        return sdk;
    }

}

pom.xml has
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-sdk</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-logback-appender-1.0</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-logs</artifactId>
            <version>1.26.0-alpha</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-http-logs</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.32.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-sender-okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>1.37.0</version> </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-sender-jdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.37.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>

logback-spring.xml has
<appender name="OpenTelemetry"
              class="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.appender.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender">
        <captureExperimentalAttributes>false</captureExperimentalAttributes>
        <captureCodeAttributes>true</captureCodeAttributes>
        <captureMarkerAttribute>true</captureMarkerAttribute>
        <captureKeyValuePairAttributes>true</captureKeyValuePairAttributes>
        <captureLoggerContext>true</captureLoggerContext>
        <captureMdcAttributes>*</captureMdcAttributes>
    </appender>

Problem Statement:
While running the application , I'm getting
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/opentelemetry/exporter/internal/okhttp/OkHttpExporterBuilder
    at io.opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.http.logs.OtlpHttpLogRecordExporterBuilder.<init>(OtlpHttpLogRecordExporterBuilder.java:29)
    at io.opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.http.logs.OtlpHttpLogRecordExporter.builder(OtlpHttpLogRecordExporter.java:44)
    at com.se.cc.cwp.api.config.OpenTelemetryLogConfiguration.initializeOpenTelemetryConfig(OpenTelemetryLogConfiguration.java:68)

Options Tried:
My code attempts to use the OtlpHttpLogRecordExporter class, which presumably comes from the opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-logs library (version 1.26.0-alpha).
However, the code also tries to access the OkHttpExporterBuilder class, which is an internal implementation detail present in opentelemetry-exporter-common (version might be inferred from the error message).
The class version incompatibility between these libraries is causing the ClassNotFoundException.So , I tried with different version of opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-logs and opentelemetry-exporter-common. There is no luck .
Any experts guidance would be helpful.

The below steps are executed to get rid of the issues.

In other module the opentelemetry-sdk was referred. I removed it from other module.

2.After modifying the dependency details as follows, the application is able to push the log to Otel collector.
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-logback-appender-1.0</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
            <version>1.37.0</version>
        </dependency>
      
  

3.And I changed the port to 4318 in the endpoint- http://10.20.36.68:4317/v1/logs
